# Need help removing duplicate columns in a mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, loops, html-table

I have a website that returns results by country. There is a query that returns this, then I use a loop to output the data. The only problem is that for one of these, there is a sub-50 column and the results are the same all the way to the sub-36 column. I need help removing the duplicate columns.

```
// By country
// sort countries by most subXs in descending order
arsort($country_sub{$dsub});
// print results
echo "<b><span style='font-size:20px;'>By Country</span></b>";
echo "<table><tr style='font-weight:bold;'><td style='width:100px;'>Country</td><td>sub".$dsub."</td>";
for($i=$dsub-1; $i>=$x; $i--){ echo "<td>sub".$i."</td>"; }
echo "</tr>";
foreach($country_sub{$dsub} as $country => $value){
 echo "<tr><td>".$country."</td><td>".$value."</td>";
 for($i=$dsub-1; $i>=$x; $i--){
 if (isset($country_sub{$i}[$country])) {
  echo "<td>".$country_sub{$i}[$country]."</td>";
 } else{
  echo "<td></td>";

 }
 echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table><br/>";
```

The array `$country_sub{$dsub}` contains the number of people with that result or less. The foreach loop is what outputs the top numbers, and the for loop is what outputs the results itself.

You can see where this code is used at this link: http://cubingstats.netau.net/3bld/index.php. It's used in the "By Country" section. All I want is in that table, to show sub 36 and sub 27 (the ones listed above). Any help is extremely useful!

EDIT: Lines 26-32 (see comments below for link) show the addOne function, which is what adds it to the array. This is then used on lines 48-50 and 68-70 as the results are displayed.

Comment: how about the query and the output? that would be helpful

Comment: You can try the GROUP BY value on your query

Comment: It is your query that is in question...  Would be helpful to see that.

Comment: It's actually not really run by a query. As the results are posted on the page the value is added to the array. You can see the full source code at http://pastie.org/private/immrnodeksobcdbdyz3g
The query works just fine, it's just that I have to be able to remove duplicate columns in a sense. A user on the forums said the easiest way to do that is to compare each column and use a loop to remove them, but I wasn't able to get that to work

Comment: I see 5 queries in your code...  How is it not run by one?

Comment: As I said, it's basically added to an array as the results from the query are being displayed. So it's not a direct result of the query, but rather a second-hand piece of code in a sense

Comment: Well in the query that fills the arrays do what Itay Moav -Malimovka says below.

Comment: That would do nothing, since each value is distinct (I have a PK set up). Is there a simple way to compare each column for duplicates? I'd prefer not to have to edit anything outside the code in the original post, but I can if necessary. If there's a solution that I'm just failing to see, please show it to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SQL query, add `DISTINCT` just after the `SELECT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT fields,fields...fields
FROM...
```